# ruby on rails fleximage plugin

Tags: ruby

How do I display the image in a view?

The documentation says:

```
<%= image_tag formatted_photo_path(@photo, :jpg) %>
```

This is not what I want.

I just want to display an image on a view I don't care about the url.

E.g., Avatar.

Do I need to write a path to the directory or is a method already made?

/public/images/avatar/id

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does the example above not render something like this to the view?

```
<img src="/path-to-generated-image.jpg"/>
```